# Sorting array of objects by different items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have a JSON:

```
[{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "url" : "thisistheurl.com",
  "status" : "Downloaded"
},{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "url" : "thisistheurl.com",
  "status" : "Downloaded"
},{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "url" : "thisistheurl.com",
  "status" : "Not downloaded"
}]
```

I have this function to sort by title:

```
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var nameA = a.status,
        nameB = b.status;
    if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
        return -1;
    if (nameA > nameB)
        return 1;
    return 0; //default return value (no sorting)
});
```

Is there a way to order by both status and title? So all with status "Downloaded" are kinda grouped AND sorted by title, and next "Not downloaded" and sorted by title. I would also like "Downloaded" to be the first divider.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your desired sort ? ?

Answer (score 0):

If status is the same then order by title like

```
var array = [{
    "title": "title you desire2",
    "url": "thisistheurl.com",
    "status": "Downloaded"
}, {
    "title": "title you desire1",
    "url": "thisistheurl.com",
    "status": "Downloaded"
}, {
    "title": "title you desire",
    "url": "thisistheurl.com",
    "status": "Not downloaded"
}];

function sortString(a, b) {
    if (a < b) { //sort string ascending
        return -1;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var status = sortString(a.status, b.status);
    if (status == 0) {
        return sortString(a.title, b.title);
    }
    return status;
});

console.log(array)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kuyn356v/1/)

Comment: @janlindso sorry what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Because `'D'` from `'Downloaded'` comes before `'N'` from `'Not downloaded'` you can do a standard string comparison on the status, followed by one based on title if they're equal.

```
if (a.status == b.status) {
    return a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
} else {
    return a.status.localCompare(b.status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting multisorting on the array based on the `title` and `status` columns. If so the below will be helpful.

**Comparer**

```
var comparer = function(x,y){ 
                return x.localeCompare(y); 
               }
```

Decorator to obatin the sort value

```
var getComparer = function(field,fn){ 
       return function(x,y){ 
         return fn(x[field],y[field]); 
      }
 }
```

Now have the field to be order in a array as follows.

```
var sorts = ["status","title"]; 
var arr = ArraytoSort;
for(var i=0; i < sorts.lenght; i++){
  arr = arr.sort(getComparer(sorts[i],comparer))  
}
```

Now the `arr` will have the array sorted with `status` and `title`. And in the above `comparer`, i have not handled `null` and `undefined` values. And the sort is also performed in `ascending`. For `descending` order just multiply the sort comparer result with `-1`